# How should I handle this Unexpected Indent?

Tags: python

When I tried to run this code, it gives me the error message of line21 UnexpectedIndent. How do I go about this? Thanks.

```
for filepath in matches:
    with open (filepath,'rt') as mytext:
         mytext=mytext.read()

         print re.findall(r'NSF\s+Org\s+\:\s+(\w+)',mytext)  #This line just aims to diagnose the problem.
         matchOrg=re.findall(r'NSF\s+Org\s+\:\s+(\w+)',mytext)[0]
         capturedorgs.append(matchOrg)
```

When I got rid of the `print re.findall(r'NSF\s+Org\s+\:\s+(\w+)',mytext)`, the error message is `MatchOrg... list out of range`.

Going to meeting. Will check back all replied after 4p.

Comment: You're using tabs inconsistently.

Comment: Have you mixed tab and space indentation?

Comment: Could you please be more specific please? I am not quite clear about your comment. Thanks.

Comment: When your primary problem is solved you should consider to self-answer or to close/delete the question if it's as trivial as this one. When then another problem occurs, please don't change your question (almost) entirely. Instead, try to solve the problem yourself, and then ask another question if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

In your text editor use the option to show all characters. Make sure indentations are consistently represented either with spaces or tabs and not a mix of both.

At times when you copy snippets of code from other sources, the indentation from your source and the other may differ causing the python interpreter to throw the unexpected indentation error as below

[image]

Comment: Will the downvoter please explain what is wrong with the answer?

Answer (score -1):

The line `mytext=...` is indented with a tab, and the rest is indented with spaces. Use either tabs or spaces, but don't mix them. The use of spaces is encouraged over the use of tabs.